# Android : Which layout to create this

Tags: android, layout, styles

I would like to know how can I create this area:

- It's a rectangle (shape) at the item row botton.
- It contains 3 icons with 3 associated texts; all these icons must have a fix position, and the text associated has just a left padding.

What is the best layout to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout`. It is very easy to use and all items you add will be added next to each other (or below each other if you set the orientation to vertical)

Comment: Yes, but to have fix positions for my icons, I must to set a width for each composant, right ? (for icons + texts)

Comment: Put the icon with its text in another `LinearLayout`, so you have 3 `LinearLayout`s in the big `LinearLayout`, set the width of the `LinearLayout`s to 0dp and set their weight to 1. This way they will stretch in the width.